# Saving reactive data collected in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app to illustrate the elicitation of prior distributions, mainly for teaching purposes.

In the app, people are asked to make 10 guesses about how many days it will take until it will next rain in Liverpool.

Their guesses are plotted in a graph and displayed in a table as they are inputed to aid understanding.

When they press the Submit button, a single .csv file containing their responses should be uploaded to a dropbox folder (for subsequent analysis).

(Much of this code is taken from the [Persistent Data Storage in Shiny Apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) example).

Everything works beautifully, expect that when the Submit button is pressed, multiple .csv files are uploaded to the dropbox folder.

I can't figure out how to save output as only one file, but suspect it is something to do with the `observe` calls.

Any help gratefully received.

```r
require(shiny)
#> Loading required package: shiny
library(tidyverse)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1.9000     ✔ purrr   0.2.4     
#> ✔ tibble  1.4.1          ✔ dplyr   0.7.4     
#> ✔ tidyr   0.7.2          ✔ stringr 1.2.0     
#> ✔ readr   1.1.1          ✔ forcats 0.2.0
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
library(rdrop2)
#Define output directory
outputDir <-
  "output"
#Define all variables to be collected
fieldsAll <- c("name", "type", "g1", "g2", "g3","g4",
               "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9", "g10")
#Define all mandatory variables
fieldsMandatory <- c("name", "type", "g1", "g2", "g3",
                     "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9",
                     "g10")
#Label mandatory fields
labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(label,
          span("*", class = "mandatory_star"))
}
#Get current Epoch time
epochTime <- function() {
  return(as.integer(Sys.time()))
}
#Get a formatted string of the timestamp
humanTime <- function() {
  format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%OS")
}
#CSS to use in the app
appCSS <-
  ".mandatory_star { color: red; }
.shiny-input-container { margin-top: 25px; }
#thankyou_msg { margin-left: 15px; }
#error { color: red; }
body { background: #fcfcfc; }
#header { background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; margin: -20px -15px 0; padding: 15px 15px 10px; }
"
#UI
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),

    headerPanel(
      'How many days until it next rains in Liverpool?'
    ),

    sidebarPanel(
      id = "form",
      textInput("name", labelMandatory("Enter name"), value = ""),
      selectInput(
        "type",
        labelMandatory("Select which group best describes you"),
        choices = c("", "Manager", "IT",
                    "Finance"),
        selected = ""
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g1",
        labelMandatory("Guess 1"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g2",
        labelMandatory("Guess 2"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g3",
        labelMandatory("Guess 3"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g4",
        labelMandatory("Guess 4"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g5",
        labelMandatory("Guess 5"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g6",
        labelMandatory("Guess 6"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g7",
        labelMandatory("Guess 7"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g8",
        labelMandatory("Guess 8"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g9",
        labelMandatory("Guess 9"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g10",
        labelMandatory("Guess 10"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      p("Your guesses will appear here:"),
      br(),
      br(),
      plotOutput("plot"),
      br(),
      p(
        "After you are happy with your guesses, press submit to send data to the database."
      ),
      br(),
      tableOutput("table"),
      br(),
      actionButton("Submit", "Submit"),

      fluidRow(shinyjs::hidden(div(
        id = "thankyou_msg",
        h3("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!")
      )))
    )
  )
)
#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Gather all the form inputs
  formData <- reactive({
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    data.frame(names = names(x),
               values = unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
  })

  #Save the results to a file
  saveData <- function(data) {
    # Create a unique file name
    fileName <-
      sprintf("%s_%s_drive_time.csv",
              humanTime(),
              digest::digest(data))
    # Write the data to a temporary file locally
    filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
    write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
    # Upload the file to Dropbox
    drop_upload(filePath, path = outputDir)
  }

  #Observe for when all mandatory fields are completed
  observe({
    fields_filled <-
      fieldsMandatory %>%
      sapply(function(x)
        ! is.na(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != "") %>%
      all

    shinyjs::toggleState("Submit", fields_filled)



    # When the Submit button is clicked, submit the response
    observeEvent(input$Submit, {
      # User-experience stuff
      shinyjs::disable("Submit")
      shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")

      tryCatch({
        saveData(formData())
        shinyjs::reset("form")
        shinyjs::hide("form")
        shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")
      })
    })

    # isolate data input
    values <- reactiveValues()

    output$table <- renderTable({
      input$addButton

      Name <- isolate({
        input$name
      })
      Type <- isolate({
        input$type
      })
      Guess1 <- isolate({
        input$g1
      })
      Guess2 <- isolate({
        input$g2
      })
      Guess3 <- isolate({
        input$g3
      })
      Guess4 <- isolate({
        input$g4
      })
      Guess5 <- isolate({
        input$g5
      })
      Guess6 <- isolate({
        input$g6
      })
      Guess7 <- isolate({
        input$g7
      })
      Guess8 <- isolate({
        input$g8
      })
      Guess9 <- isolate({
        input$g9
      })
      Guess10 <- isolate({
        input$g10
      })

      df <-
        data_frame(Name, Type, Guess1, Guess2, Guess3, Guess4, 
                   Guess5, Guess6, Guess7, Guess8, Guess9, Guess10)

      df
       })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      input$addButton

      x1 <- isolate({
        input$g1
      })
      x2 <- isolate({
        input$g2
      })
      x3 <- isolate({
        input$g3
      })
      x4 <- isolate({
        input$g4
      })
      x5 <- isolate({
        input$g5
      })
      x6 <- isolate({
        input$g6
      })
      x7 <- isolate({
        input$g7
      })
      x8 <- isolate({
        input$g8
      })
      x9 <- isolate({
        input$g9
      })
      x10 <- isolate({
        input$g10
      })

      df2 <-
        data_frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) %>%
        gather()

      ggplot(df2) +
        geom_histogram(aes(x = as.numeric(value)), fill = "#18a7b5", stat =
                         "count") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = seq(1, 10, 1),
                   col = "white",
                   lwd = 1) +
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 4),
                   linetype = "dashed",
                   colour = "black") +
        stat_function(
          fun = function(x, mean, sd, n, bw) {
            dnorm(x = x,
                  mean = mean,
                  sd = sd) * n * bw
          },
          args = c(
            mean = mean(df2$value),
            sd = sd(df2$value),
            n = length(df2$value),
            bw = 1
          ),
          colour = "#b5185f"
        ) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                           breaks = c(0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                           breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) +
        labs(x = "Number of days until rains", y = "",
             title = "Estimated number of days until rain") +
        theme(legend.position = "none")

    })
  })
})
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks - that still seems to result in multiple files being outputted, suggesting it is something to do with the nesting of my `observe` calls.

Comment: @PeterMacPherson Ideally, you want the same table that you are displaying to be written as a csv or uploaded to dropbox, Is that right?

Comment: @armrrs - Yes that is correct

Comment: While I'm still trying to figure out the issue, it seems you've got observeEvent inside an observe that seems to be the potential reason for multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed a couple of things:
* Took the `observeEvent` Out of `observe`
* In fact, reduced the scope of `observe`
* `isolate` wasn't required while assigning in table creation

```
require(shiny)
#> Loading required package: shiny
library(tidyverse)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1.9000     ✔ purrr   0.2.4     
#> ✔ tibble  1.4.1          ✔ dplyr   0.7.4     
#> ✔ tidyr   0.7.2          ✔ stringr 1.2.0     
#> ✔ readr   1.1.1          ✔ forcats 0.2.0
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
library(rdrop2)
#Define output directory
outputDir <-
  "output"
#Define all variables to be collected
fieldsAll <- c("name", "type", "g1", "g2", "g3","g4",
               "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9", "g10")
#Define all mandatory variables
fieldsMandatory <- c("name", "type", "g1", "g2", "g3",
                     "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9",
                     "g10")
#Label mandatory fields
labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(label,
          span("*", class = "mandatory_star"))
}
#Get current Epoch time
epochTime <- function() {
  return(as.integer(Sys.time()))
}
#Get a formatted string of the timestamp
humanTime <- function() {
  format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%OS")
}
#CSS to use in the app
appCSS <-
  ".mandatory_star { color: red; }
.shiny-input-container { margin-top: 25px; }
#thankyou_msg { margin-left: 15px; }
#error { color: red; }
body { background: #fcfcfc; }
#header { background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; margin: -20px -15px 0; padding: 15px 15px 10px; }
"
#UI
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),

    headerPanel(
      'How many days until it next rains in Liverpool?'
    ),

    sidebarPanel(
      id = "form",
      textInput("name", labelMandatory("Enter name"), value = ""),
      selectInput(
        "type",
        labelMandatory("Select which group best describes you"),
        choices = c("", "Manager", "IT",
                    "Finance"),
        selected = ""
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g1",
        labelMandatory("Guess 1"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g2",
        labelMandatory("Guess 2"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g3",
        labelMandatory("Guess 3"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g4",
        labelMandatory("Guess 4"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g5",
        labelMandatory("Guess 5"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g6",
        labelMandatory("Guess 6"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g7",
        labelMandatory("Guess 7"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g8",
        labelMandatory("Guess 8"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g9",
        labelMandatory("Guess 9"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      ),
      numericInput(
        "g10",
        labelMandatory("Guess 10"),
        value = "",
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      p("Your guesses will appear here:"),
      br(),
      br(),
      plotOutput("plot"),
      br(),
      p(
        "After you are happy with your guesses, press submit to send data to the database."
      ),
      br(),
      tableOutput("table"),
      br(),
      actionButton("Submit", "Submit"),

      fluidRow(shinyjs::hidden(div(
        id = "thankyou_msg",
        h3("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!")
      )))
    )
  )
)
#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Gather all the form inputs
  formData <- reactive({
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    data.frame(names = names(x),
               values = unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
  })

  #Save the results to a file
  saveData <- function(data) {
    # Create a unique file name
    fileName <-
      sprintf("%s_%s_drive_time.csv",
              humanTime(),
              digest::digest(data))
    # Write the data to a temporary file locally
    filePath <- file.path('C:\\Users\\SA31\\Desktop\\btc', fileName)
    write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
    # Upload the file to Dropbox
    #drop_upload(filePath, path = outputDir)
  }



  # When the Submit button is clicked, submit the response
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    # User-experience stuff
    shinyjs::disable("Submit")
    shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")

    tryCatch({
      #saveData(formData())
      shinyjs::reset("form")
      shinyjs::hide("form")
      shinyjs::show("thankyou_msg")
    })
    #write.csv(create_table(),'submitted.csv')
    saveData(create_table())
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE, ignoreNULL = T)



  #Observe for when all mandatory fields are completed
  observe({
    fields_filled <-
      fieldsMandatory %>%
      sapply(function(x)
        ! is.na(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != "") %>%
      all

    shinyjs::toggleState("Submit", fields_filled)

  })

        # isolate data input
    values <- reactiveValues()


      create_table <- reactive({
        input$addButton

        Name <- input$name
        Type <- input$type
        Guess1 <- input$g1
        Guess2 <- input$g2
        Guess3 <- input$g3
        Guess4 <- input$g4
        Guess5 <- input$g5
        Guess6 <- input$g6
        Guess7 <- input$g7
        Guess8 <- input$g8
        Guess9 <- input$g9
        Guess10 <- input$g10
        df <-
          data_frame(Name, Type, Guess1, Guess2, Guess3, Guess4, 
                     Guess5, Guess6, Guess7, Guess8, Guess9, Guess10)

        df
      })



    output$table <- renderTable(create_table())

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      input$addButton

      x1 <- isolate({
        input$g1
      })
      x2 <- isolate({
        input$g2
      })
      x3 <- isolate({
        input$g3
      })
      x4 <- isolate({
        input$g4
      })
      x5 <- isolate({
        input$g5
      })
      x6 <- isolate({
        input$g6
      })
      x7 <- isolate({
        input$g7
      })
      x8 <- isolate({
        input$g8
      })
      x9 <- isolate({
        input$g9
      })
      x10 <- isolate({
        input$g10
      })

      df2 <-
        data_frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) %>%
        gather()

      ggplot(df2) +
        geom_histogram(aes(x = as.numeric(value)), fill = "#18a7b5", stat =
                         "count") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = seq(1, 10, 1),
                   col = "white",
                   lwd = 1) +
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 4),
                   linetype = "dashed",
                   colour = "black") +
        stat_function(
          fun = function(x, mean, sd, n, bw) {
            dnorm(x = x,
                  mean = mean,
                  sd = sd) * n * bw
          },
          args = c(
            mean = mean(df2$value),
            sd = sd(df2$value),
            n = length(df2$value),
            bw = 1
          ),
          colour = "#b5185f"
        ) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                           breaks = c(0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                           breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) +
        labs(x = "Number of days until rains", y = "",
             title = "Estimated number of days until rain") +
        theme(legend.position = "none")


  })
})
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @amrss - thank you, but this now seems to give double the number of .csv files... I note in your comment above to the original question, you mention the `observeEvent` inside the `observe` as a possible culprit, which seems plausible. However, whenever I try to rationalise this, I lose either the reactive updating of the graph and table, or saving the table

Comment: @PeterMacPherson Finally it works using your existing functions but with some changes to observe

Comment: @amrss - this is awesome. The .csv file now saves correctly... However, have lost the interactive nature of the graph. Whereas the table automatically populates with values when values are entered into the form, the graph is no longer updated...

Comment: @amrss as a follow-up, I managed to get the reactive plot working too by building upon your `create_table` function to make a `create_plot` function. Many thanks for your assistance. Much appreciated!

Comment: @PeterMacPherson Sorry couldn't respond earlier. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that the question is older. But searching for "saving reactive data" in shiny, i did not find a MWE here and searched elsewhere.

As the question attracted over 2k views i share my findings and add a mwe myself:

**Short answer:**

To save reactive data, transform it to a list with `reactiveValuesToList`.

**Minimal working example:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("txt", "enter text", "default"),
  actionButton("save", label = "Save reactive value to disk")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  global <- reactiveValues()
        
  observeEvent(input$save,{
    global$txt <- input$txt
    to_save <- reactiveValuesToList(global)
    saveRDS(to_save, file = "saved.rds")
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    
    loaded <- readRDS("saved.rds")
    print(loaded$txt)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```